# How to replace embedded credentials in subresource requests?

Tags: ajax, angular, ionic-framework

I get this error in the console in my Ionic app:

```
[Deprecation] Subresource requests whose URLs contain embedded credentials (e.g. `https://user:pass@host/`) are deprecated, and will be blocked in M59, around June 2017.
```

The line of code is a URL for an ajax request:

```
  function dbUrl() {
        return unescape(encodeURIComponent("http://idname:idnamepasswd@mysite.com/pDB.json"));
  }
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The five-parameter version of the `XMLHttpRequest.open` method allows you to specify the username and password.

```
xhr.open(method, url, async, username, password)
```

Here's the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/open) and the [spec](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#the-open()-method).