# Passing basic auth credentials in Google Chrome shows the pop again

Tags: authentication, selenium-webdriver, basic-authentication, watir

I am using watir(Ruby selenium package) to try and login to url using basic auth

I pass the credentials like so

```
 https://username:password@nagios.com
```

However when the browser opens, i get a popup to enter the credentials again.

The code that i use is as follows

```
driver = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
driver.goto "https://username:password@nagios.com"
```

The above code opens the browser -> goes to the url but give the popup to enter the credentials again.

How do i login to the url using basic auth?

Comment: What browser? It's possible that either the site or the driver does not support basic authentication right now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Turns out that Chrome has stopped supporting passing credentials in the url after version 52. more info https://medium.com/@lmakarov/say-goodbye-to-urls-with-embedded-credentials-b051f6c7b6a3

To fix this you need to set an argument  `--disable-blink-features="BlockCredentialedSubresources"` while launching the browser. what this does is that it disable that feature

More info [Bypass blocking of subresource requests whose URLs contain embedded credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45039335/bypass-blocking-of-subresource-requests-whose-urls-contain-embedded-credentials?source=post_page)

This is my final code which works

```
 args = ['--disable-software-rasterizer',
                    '--disable-blink-features="BlockCredentialedSubresources"',
                    '--no-proxy-server',
                    '--disable-gpu',
                    '--no-sandbox',
                    '--ignore-certificate-errors']
driver = Watir::Browser.new :chrome, options: {args: args}
driver.goto "https://username:password@nagios.com"
```